# Processing different files through Apache camel in different pods

Tags: java, spring-boot, multiprocessing, apache-camel

1. When I put multiple files in a location, and from there Apache camel will pick those files  and process it.
2. But suppose if I have multiple pods say Pod A and Pod B to pick multiple files say file 1 and file 2, then how camel came to know that if file 1 is picked up by Pod A then the file 1 should not be picked up by Pod B.
3. Now Pod A can pick file 2 only.

Comment: You can configure routes to execute in an order refer this documentation. https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this service must be single instance . also u can do it in kubernetes . it is singleton application pattern . n pods are standing but only one is working. leader pod run other pods watch him in this pattern . more details https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-singleton-application-pattern  and second solution [How to read file only once when app deployed on two nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355877/how-to-read-file-only-once-when-app-deployed-on-two-nodes/67359901#67359901)