# How to read file only once when app deployed on two nodes

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I'm going to read files from SFTP location line by line:

```java
@Override
public void configure() {
    from(sftpLocationUrl)
            .routeId("route-name")
            .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
            .streaming()
            .bean(service, "build")
            .to(String.format("activemq:%s", queueName));
}
```

But this application will be deployed on two nodes, and I think that in this case, I can get an unstable and unpredictable application work because the same lines of the file can be read twice.
Is there a way to avoid such duplicates in this case?

Comment: You can move the file to some other location, after reading, so that other node does not read it again.

Comment: Hello @pratap! I think it won't work in my case, because my app on nodes will read this file at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel has some (experimental) **clustering** capabilities - see [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/clustering.html).

In your particular case, you could model a route which is taking the leadership when starting the directory polling, preventing thereby other nodes from picking the (same or other) files.

Comment: @AndreiKulik See especially the "Master Component" section. Theoretically, if your consumer endpoint is `from("ftp://foo")`, replacing it with `from("master:my-ns:ftp://foo")` is supposed to to the job :-)

Comment: if it really works, I'd be very happy.
Thanks a lot again :)
This isn't the first time you have helped me. I am very glad that the Apache Camel has support. I feel like your main karma magnifier :D

Answer (score 1):

soluion is active passive mode . “In active/passive mode, you have a single master instance polling for files, while all the other instances (slaves) are passive. For this strategy to work, some kind of locking mechanism must be in use to ensure that only the node holding the lock is the master and all other nodes are on standby.”

it can implement with hazelcast, consul or zookeper

```
public class FileConsumerRoute extends RouteBuilder {

private int delay;
private String name;

public FileConsumerRoute(String name, int delay) {
    this.name = name;
    this.delay = delay;
}

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // read files from the shared directory
    from("file:target/inbox" +
            "?delete=true")
        // setup route policy to be used
        .routePolicyRef("myPolicy")
        .log(name + " - Received file: ${file:name}")
        .delay(delay)
        .log(name + " - Done file:     ${file:name}")
        .to("file:target/outbox");
}}
```

ServerBar

```
public class ServerBar {

private Main main;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerBar bar = new ServerBar();
    bar.boot();
}

public void boot() throws Exception {
    // setup the hazelcast route policy
    ConsulRoutePolicy routePolicy = new ConsulRoutePolicy();
    // the service names must be same in the foo and bar server
    routePolicy.setServiceName("myLock");
    routePolicy.setTtl(5);

    main = new Main();
    // bind the hazelcast route policy to the name myPolicy which we refer to from the route
    main.bind("myPolicy", routePolicy);
    // add the route and and let the route be named Bar and use a little delay when processing the files
    main.addRouteBuilder(new FileConsumerRoute("Bar", 100));
    main.run();
}
```

}

Server Foo

```
public class ServerFoo {

private Main main;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerFoo foo = new ServerFoo();
    foo.boot();
}

public void boot() throws Exception {
    // setup the hazelcast route policy
    ConsulRoutePolicy routePolicy = new ConsulRoutePolicy();
    // the service names must be same in the foo and bar server
    routePolicy.setServiceName("myLock");
    routePolicy.setTtl(5);

    main = new Main();
    // bind the hazelcast route policy to the name myPolicy which we refer to from the route
    main.bind("myPolicy", routePolicy);
    // add the route and and let the route be named Bar and use a little delay when processing the files
    main.addRouteBuilder(new FileConsumerRoute("Foo", 100));
    main.run();
}}
```

Source : Camel In Action 2nd Edition

Comment: Hello @eray! Wow, I'm really confused by your answer I need to look at it more because it sounds pretty difficult for me. I didn't think that it would be so difficult to do it using the standard Apache Camel means. I am still hoping to find a simpler solution. Anyway, I'll take a look at this solution. Thx!